# How to create a list of data which is read from files in R?

Tags: r, database, list, for-loop, file-read

I have a list of paths for 104 different shp files. I want to create a list of files, which acts as an array such that the [i]th element of this list contains the file located in path[i]. The coding language I'm working in is R.

My problem is creating a list that contains files in their original format, not an integer representation of those files. When I create a simple list and I iterate my list of paths with a for loop and assign the file in the paths[i] to the [i]th element of my list, What I get as an obs dataset is a list of nonsensical integers in only one field, while each of my original files contains 43 different fields.

How can I create a list that maintains the structures of original files so that I can copy each of my files in this list and have a dataset containing the information in my shp files? please help me.

Comment: You'd just create a list and store the elements as list[[i]] <- element[i], the problem you face most likely stems from the fact that the data is not read correclty, e.g. wrong decimal separator or column separator. Please try to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example with some data and code, and we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the path of all the files stored in a folder using `list.files` :

```
path_of_files <- list.files('/folder/to/shp/files', pattern = '\\.shp$', full.names = TRUE)
```

Let's say you use `read_sf` to read the shape files. To read all the files you can use `lapply` like :

```
list_files <- lapply(path_of_files, sf::read_sf)
```